# Duvida sobre JavaEE com Wildfly 18

Tags: java, java-ee, wildfly, back-end, ejb

Gostaria de saber do que se trata esse log.

```
[org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'ContaService' in deployment unit 'deployment "Backend.war"' are as follows:

    java:global/Backend/ContaService!com.hybridnetwork.service.ContaService
    java:app/Backend/ContaService!com.hybridnetwork.service.ContaService
    java:module/ContaService!com.hybridnetwork.service.ContaService
    ejb:/Backend/ContaService!com.hybridnetwork.service.ContaService
    java:global/Backend/ContaService
    java:app/Backend/ContaService
    java:module/ContaService
```

Anotei como um simples stateless:

```
@Stateless
public class ContaService {

    public List<ContaDTO> list() {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

}
```

Injetei da seguinte forma:

```
@Path("contas")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ContaRest {

    @Inject
    ContaService contaService;

    @GET
    public Response listarTodos() {
        return Response.ok(contaService.list()).build();
    }

}
```

Estrutura de pastas usada:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Oi Yan! Em vez de usar a imagem, coloque o log em formato texto na sua pergunta. Pense que se alguém tiver um problema parecido com o seu ele não vai conseguir encontrar esta pergunta sua e ver a resposta se usar uma imagem para explicar o seu problema.

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback, o log esta ai ;)

Comment: como que está a classe ContaService ? pode publicada? Como que você injetou essa classe?

Comment: Alem de corrigir a pergunta postei os detalhes solicitados, obrigado pelo feedback também ;)

Comment: Para teste, modifica a anotação `@Inject` para `@EJB` na classe `ContaRest`, se funcionar eu posto a solução como resposta, você criou a interface do `ContaService` ?